# php stopped working all together

Tags: php, wampserver

I am playing around with php through WAMP, trying to setup a small MySQL database and a webpage that can display and search through it. Everything worked for about 2 hours and I managed to make a php page that gets the rows from a given sql table and makes a html table and displays it.

All of a sudden the script stopped working. Even if I comment out or remove ALL code except the following all I get in Google Chrome is "Hello HTML world! and... "

```
<html>
<body>
Hello HTML world! <br>
and... <br>
<?php
echo "Hello PHP World";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

The above code is in a .php file in the www folder of WAMP. As I mentioned above it was already working after the first install up until an hour ago. FWIW phpmyadmin is still working properly.

I already tried the following, in this order:
1) restart browser
2) restart computer
3) reinstall WAMP
4) clearing browser cache
5) editting "C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts" to replace "::1             localhost" 
with "127.0.0.1       localhost"
6) search this site and anything else that shows up in google search.

What could it be?

edit: Thank you for the quick replies!

I am opening the file in Chrome with the following URL "file:///C:/Program%20Files/wamp/www/new.php"

I have used it exactly the same about an hour ago and it worked perfectly back then.

If i use the "view source" option I see the content of the .php file, exactly the same as the code block in this post.

Comment: How are you opening the file exactly?

Comment: if you view the HTML source do you see your PHP code in it?

Comment: To view the html source: click CTRL-U inside the browser window or select something like View->Page Source.

Comment: Thank you for the quick replies.I am opening the file in Chrome with the following URL "file:///C:/Program%20Files/wamp/www/new.php"

I have used it exactly the same about an hour ago and it worked perfectly back then.

If i use the "view source" option I see the content of the .php file, exactly the same as the code block in this post

Comment: Why don't you open as `http://localhost/new.php`? And will that work?

Comment: Oh, using  http://localhost/new.php works perfectly! Thanks!

Comment: You are NOT opening the file from server. You are just opening it like we open those songs, movies.

Comment: Altough im still curious as to why. I am 99% confident that the old url used to work this morning. If you've got an explanation or a website on the subject I would be interested to hear it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you access it it via `file:///.....` it will load the file without running it through the web server. So PHP will never get to run the script.

You need to access it via `http://localhost/path/to/filename.php` in order for it to run through the server and have PHP do its thing.